# SQL Joining multiple tables, columns from 3rd table not showing

Tags: sql, select, join

Hello i've the following SQL query

```
 Select catalogid , numitems, allitems - numitems ignoreditems
        from ( 
        select i.catalogid,
         sum(case when (ocardtype in ('PayPal','Sofort') OR
                        ocardtype in ('mastercard','visa') and
                        odate is not null) then numitems
                        else 0 end) numitems,
         sum(numitems) allitems 
        from orders o
        join oitems i on i.orderid=o.orderid
        join products T1 on T1.catalogid = i.catalogid
        group by i.catalogid
        ) X
```

in the last join statement table products contains 8 columns and they don't show in the result query, i can only see the columns catalogid, numitems and ignoreditems, so what am i doing wrong, if i have to select those columns in order to make them appear how can i do it with this syntax?

Comment: Why nested select used? May be to select (allitems - numitems) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select catalogid , numitems, allitems - numitems ignoreditems, X.c1,X.c2,X.c3,X.c4,X.c5,X.c6,X.c7,X.c8
    from ( 
    select i.catalogid,
     sum(case when (ocardtype in ('PayPal','Sofort') OR
                    ocardtype in ('mastercard','visa') and
                    odate is not null) then numitems
                    else 0 end) numitems,
     sum(numitems) allitems ,
     T1.c1, T1.c2, T1.c3, T1.c4, T1.c5, T1.c6, T1.c7, T1.c8
    from orders o
    join oitems i on i.orderid=o.orderid
    join products T1 on T1.catalogid = i.catalogid
    group by i.catalogid, T1.c1, T1.c2, T1.c3, T1.c4, T1.c5, T1.c6, T1.c7, T1.c8
    ) X
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just querying those three columns. If you want columns from products to show in the resultset, just add them to the select statement. You could add them one by one or just add T1.* to query all of them:

```
Select catalogid , numitems, allitems - numitems ignoreditems, X.columnName1, X.ColumnName2, X.*
from ( 
select i.catalogid,
sum(case when (ocardtype in ('PayPal','Sofort') OR
ocardtype in ('mastercard','visa') and
odate is not null) then numitems
else 0 end) numitems,
sum(numitems) allitems,
-- This
T1.ColumnName1, T1.ColumName2, ...
--- or this way
T1.*
from orders o
join oitems i on i.orderid=o.orderid
join products T1 on T1.catalogid = i.catalogid
group by i.catalogid
) X
```